# R data frame , New Vector with condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements

Hello I am new to R and I need some help

I have a data like this

```
ID Age Sex
A01 30 m
A02 35 f
B03 45 m
C99 50 m
...
```

And i would like to create a new column Group with condition like this

```
if data1$age <30 then Group is = 1
else if data1$age >=30 and data1$age <40 then Group = 2
else if data1$age >=40 and data1$age <50 then Group = 3
else data1$age >=50 group = 4


 ID Age Sex Group
A01 30  m   2
A02 35  f   2
B03 45  m   3
C99 50  m   4
```

How do i do that in R

Answer (score 4):

You can try `findInterval`, which can be used like this (using @Tim's sample data):

```
> findInterval(data1$Age, c(0, 30, 40, 50))
[1] 2 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Some good old-fashioned Base R will come in handy for your problem:

```
data1 <- data.frame(ID=c("A01", "A02", "B03", "C99"),
                    Age=c(30, 35, 45, 50),
                    Sex=c("m", "f", "m", "m"))

data1$Group[data1$Age < 30] <- 1
data1$Group[data1$Age >= 30 & data1$Age < 40] <- 2
data1$Group[data1$Age >= 40 & data1$Age < 50] <- 3
data1$Group[data1$Age >= 50] <- 4

> data1
   ID Age Sex Group
1 A01  30   m     2
2 A02  35   f     2
3 B03  45   m     2
4 C99  50   m     4
```

By the way, you miscategorized ID `A01` in your example. Since his age is 30, he belongs in group 2 according to your logic.

Comment: yup, but somthing is wrong when I apply your code, is not working properly, group 3 override group 1 and 2 ... I don't understand

Comment: I just tested my code with an extended (random) data set and it works fine.  Please post your exact error.

Comment: like for example age 20  is in group 3

Comment: Not according to my test.  I think you are doing something wrong.  I also tested the answer given by @Ananda using my sample data and it works.

Comment: This is a common mistake, I have done this more times than I wish :-)

Answer (score 2):

We can also do with `cut`

```
cut(data1$Age, c(0,seq(30,50,10),Inf), right=FALSE, labels=FALSE)
#[1] 2 2 3 4
```

EDIT: Based on @thelatemail's comments.

Comment: `cut(data1$Age, c(0,seq(30,50,10),Inf), right=FALSE, labels=FALSE)` should cover it no?